# React com rerenders and forgets data in useRef

Tags: reactjs

I'm a beginner in React trying to code a very simple 'space invaders' type of arcade game.

All goes well so far, except for the fact that when I shoot, and then when I go left or right, the parent component re-renders but also does my pad at the bottom of the screen which gets a new left value of 0, instead of keeping the value it had.

This happens exactly and I move the pad (all going fine), and then I shoot ( all goes well ), but then I try to move it again and the value of left switches back to suddenly, and that's because of rerendering and not keeping track of that pad position value.

here is my sandbox: https://ehn4f.csb.app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `stepsToRight` needed to be a `ref` to preserve value across renders. Since it was a normal `let` declaration, it always got recreated as `stepsToRight = 0` in each subsequent render and your pad would go back to the starting point.

Updated that in this fork :-

https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-chandrasekhar-hbpli?file=/src/MainGameContainer.jsx

Comment: oh thanks so much !!! i get it now....!! thanks so much for the help !!

Comment: @julBayonna Can you kindly accept this answer ? I am hungry for those reputation points.

Comment: oh yes sorry for that, i'm quite new to Stackoverflow as well, i have accepted your answer, much thanks !!!